# Aggregate inside of CASE statement inside of WHERE clause

Tags: sql, case, aggregate-functions, where-clause, having

I try to populate a temporary table with values that meet various criteria laid out in a WHERE clause. One of the clauses is a case statement that has an aggregate (SUM) function within it, which is resulting in the Msg 147 error

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery...

Can you advise how I can make this work?

My query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.id
INTO #ft
FROM someTable r
LEFT JOIN someOtherTable p ON someTable r
    ...
    ...
WHERE OtherID != '1'
    AND 
        CASE
            WHEN 
                p.Type = 'u'
                AND SUM(r.value) >= 24
            THEN '100%'
            WHEN 
                p.Type = 'g'
                AND SUM(r.value) >= 18
            THEN '100%'
        END IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: you may do aggregates inside subquery as column and apply where clause with case statement in outer query

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I wasn't able to do it exactly as you recommended, but I did create a second temporary table using a Where clause on the first temporary table to store the values I needed, which I was then able to correctly use later in the query (SELECT DISTINCT id IN tempTable2).

Comment: May you please share the sample data and expected result?